# Azure.RequestFailedException: Unexpected property 'source' found in JSON

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I'm using Azure.Messaging.EventGrid version 4.0.0-beta.4 to publish events to an Event Grid topic.

I think I have the client set up correctly and am calling the right method to publish the events, but I got this exception:

```
Azure.RequestFailedException: 'Service request failed. 
Status: 400 (Unexpected property 'source' found in JSON. Expected: 
StartObject, actual: StartArray)
```

Here's my code based on the samples given [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/eventgrid/Azure.Messaging.EventGrid):

```cs
Uri endpoint = new Uri("myEndpoint");
string accessKey = "myAccessKey";
string topicName = "MyTopic1";

EventGridPublisherClient client = new EventGridPublisherClient(
    endpoint, 
    new AzureKeyCredential(accessKey));

MyCustomObj obj = new MyCustomObj() {
     Description = "Test description",
     Name = "Test name",
     Id = 1234};

List<EventGridEvent> eventsList = new List<EventGridEvent>
    {
        new EventGridEvent(
            obj,
            "myCustomObject",
            "myEventType",
            "v1"
        )
    };

await client.SendEventsAsync(eventsList);
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. Turns out that I should be publishing `CloudEvent` instead of `EventGridEvent`. After spending a lot of time on Azure Portal, I found that the topic I'm trying to publish to accepts only `CloudEvent`. Finding this info took a lot of exploration because it's very much hidden. But here's how I found it:

When you're on the Overview tab, there's a "Json View" link right above where you'd find "Topic Endpoint":
[image]

Click that and choose the latest API Version. Here it's telling me that the `inputSchema` is `CloudEventSchemaV1_0`:

[image]

After changing the Event type, I was able to publish the event:

```cs
List<CloudEvent> eventsList = new List<CloudEvent>
    {
        new CloudEvent(
            "localhost",
            "myEventType",
            obj
        )
    };

await client.SendEventsAsync(eventsList);
```

This shouldn't have been something that caused so much trouble...

Anyways... A side thing that I'm still confused about is why are the attributes of `CloudEvent` different from those of `EventGridEvent`? Also one has a data version attribute, but the other doesn't. How do I choose which to use?